# Why isn't lightning-combobox actually setting the value to the selection?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-combobox

I have a combobox in a modal dialog that looks like this:

```html
    <template if:true={showAddTagDialog}>
        <section
            role="dialog"
            tabindex="-1"
            aria-labelledby="modal-heading-02"
            aria-modal="true"
            aria-describedby="modal-content-id-2"
            class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open"
        >
            <div if:true={showExistingTags} class="slds-modal__container">
                <header class="slds-modal__header">
                    <h2 class="slds-modal__title slds-hyphenate">Assign Tag</h2>
                </header>
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium">
                    <lightning-combobox
                        name="tag"
                        placeholder="Select Tag"
                        variant="label-hidden"
                        value={tagMenuSelection}
                        onchange={handleTagMenuChange}
                        options={tagMenuOptions}
                    >
                    </lightning-combobox>
                </div>
                <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                    <lightning-button
                        label="Cancel"
                        onclick={handleCancelAssignTag}
                    >
                </footer>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
    </template>
```

Everything works except when I click the combobox and select a value, the value isn't put into the combobox. It still shows the placeholder. `handleTagMenuChange` does get fired, and `event.detail` holds `{value: null}`.

`tagMenuSelection` is just a property on the component that's initialized to an empty string.

```js
tagMenuSelection = '';
```

`tagMenuOptions` calls an Apex method to get the tags that the current user should see. After the call it looks like this:

```js
[
    {name: "onhold", label: "#On Hold"},
    {name: "toppriority", label: "#Top Priority"},
    {name: "expiringsoon", label: "Expiring Soon"},
    {name: "firsttimebuyer", label: "First Time Buyer"},
    {name: "old", label: "Old"},
    {name: "pendingapraisal", label: "Pending Apraisal"},
    {name: "push", label: "Push"}
]
```

These options successfully appear in the menu.

`handleTagMenuChange`:

```js
handleTagMenuChange(event) {
    this.tagMenuSelection = event.detail.value;
    console.log(this.tagMenuSelection);
}
```

The console just outputs `null`.

Why does making a selection in the combobox fire the `onchange` handler but doesn't actually *change* the value?

Comment: hard to say without seeing your `tagMenuOptions` or `handleTagMenuChange` and how you are assigning `tagMenuSelection`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change your `name` key attributes to `value`, since the lightning-combobox allows

`[{value: 'something; label: 'something'}]`

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing. In other words, rtfm. 

Comment: lol, no worries, happens to everyone 